# dynamic jQuery Effects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Was wondering if there is a way in Javascript to call function/method names by string?

Scenario, writing a bit of jQuery that runs an Effect on target(s). I'd like to make this Effect Dynamic (Changeable by the user).

I guess, ideally i would be looking for something like `jQuery('target').Effect('slideDown','slow');`

Or anything that could produce the same results, with out having to have some overbearing Switch Statements like `switch(vEffect){ case 'slideDown': jQuery().slideDown(); break; }` which to me seems redundant...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the property syntax to reference a method:

```
jQuery('target')['slideDown']('slow');
```

or, if you have it in a variable:

```
var methodName = 'slideDown';
jQuery('target')[methodName]('slow');
```

You could also create your own jQuery plug-in called `effect` that took parameters like you want and then called the actual method using the above technique.

```
jQuery.fn.effect = function(methodName, speed) {
    return this[methodName](speed);
}
```

which you could then call like this:

```
jQuery('target').effect('slideDown', 'slow);
```

Comment: brilliant. Exactly what I was looking for. And thanks for the jQuery Plugin idea, that's where the question stemmed from (this plugin I'm writing). Off the top of your head, what would this be called (if I had to look it up or reference later) ?

Comment: @thesocialhacker - search for this "javascript property access by variable".